# Redirect keyboard input echo in linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, ncurses, termios

So this is a tricky one. After having run matlab in a linux terminal, somehow the echo of keyboard input is lost. That is for example if I type "ls", I don't see "ls" in the terminal but just the output from ls. So somehow I think the echoing of keyboard input has been redirected somewhere. Is there a way to manually reset or direct the keyboard echoing back to stdout?

Comment: Have you tried `reset`?

Comment: Or try: `stty sane`

Comment: agree: `reset` does both escape sequences and termio fixes (not identical to `stty sane`), but `stty` happens to apply to echoing while escape sequences do not.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few options to get around the issue you currently have, first using the stty command with sane would be useful here. Because this command will Reset all terminal settings to sane values incase it has been changed by accident. Then I would use the command stty -echo to make sure to turn off the echoing of terminal input and re-enable the echoing of the terminal with stty echo.

Here's some documentation about the stty commands: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ustty.htm